# Extrair determinado dado do array de um Json

Tags: json, angularjs

Tenho pegado um Json de uma API que retorna esse resultado:

```js
[
  {
    "marca_id": 4,
    "modelo_id": 2708,
    "versao_id": 65344,
    "cor": "Azul",
    "opcionais": [
      {
        "opcional_id": 6,
        "opcional_nome": "Airbags"
      },
      {
        "opcional_id": 10,
        "opcional_nome": "Freios ABS"
      },
      {
        "opcional_id": 18,
        "opcional_nome": "Ar Condicionado"
      },
      {
        "opcional_id": 22,
        "opcional_nome": "Direção Hidráulica"
      },
      {
        "opcional_id": 19,
        "opcional_nome": "Bancos de Couro"
      }
    ],
    "valor": "40000,00",
    "kilometragem": 97437,
    "imagens": [
      "imagem"
    ],
    "thumbs": [
      "miniatura.jpg"
    ],
    "url_ficha_registro": "0001",
    "loja": "4555"
  }
]
```

Como eu acesso para imprimir em um ng-repeat todos os itens do campo "opcionais"? Pois se eu imprimo tipo {{x.opcionais}} ou {{x.opcionais[3]}} ele me retorna o array, lógico. Pode parecer uma pergunta um tanto boba mas eu realmente estou batendo cabeça com isso, ter um ng-repeat dentro de outro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido. Caso alguem precisar esta abaixo:

```html
<div ng-repeat="dado in x.opcionais">
  {{ dado.opcional_nome }} 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dessa maneira:

```
<tr>
   <td ng-repeat="x.opcionais as dado">
     {{dado.opcional_id}}
     {{dado.opcional_nome}}
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Olá Ivan, infelizmente não funcionou. Ele imprime no código fonte o seguinte: <!-- ngRepeat: x.opcionais as dado -->  Alguma outra idéia?

Comment: Valeu ivan, encontrei a resposta já! Brigadão!

Comment: cara, eu viajei, era isso mesmo, no caso era "dado in x.opcionais" :D